# SQL count of data in many to one relationship where I want to find duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 3 table structure such that:

Table Patient - PatientID PK has a 1 to many relationship with table Appointment (PK ApptID)
Table Appointment has a 1 to many relationship with table Encounter (PK EncounterID).
ApptID is a FK for Encounter table.

Encounter table has a few notable fields.  PK: EncounterID, FK: ApptID, DateofEncounter (datetime), and Code (varchar).  The last two are not keys or anything.

What I want to do search for duplicate encounters that have the same code, same ApptID, and same DateoFEncounter.  I want a list by PatientID, then ApptID

I have this SQL which lists PatientID, ApptID, and # of Encounters.  But I don't know if those encounters are duplicates or not.  (they could be on different dates, or different codes, or what not).  I have no clue how to find those that occur on the same date with the same code.  Any advice?

```
select a.PatientID, a.ApptID, COUNT(e.EncounterID) AS NumberOfEncounters
FROM Appointment a LEFT JOIN Encounter e on e.ApptID = a.ApptID
GROUP BY a.PatientID, a.ApptID
ORDER BY COUNT(e.EncounterID) DESC
```

Comment: What would really help would be some DDL that built the tables, and populated some data. Then you could say what you're expecting from the query. I'd probably run that in a database to see what's wrong with the query your suggested, but I'm afraid that working it out from your text is too time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.PatientID, a.ApptID, COUNT(e.EncounterID) AS NumberOfEncounters
FROM Appointment a LEFT JOIN Encounter e on e.ApptID = a.ApptID
                            AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Encounter e2 WHERE e.pkEncounterID <> e2.pkEncounterID AND e.Code = e2.Code AND e.DateofEncounter = e2.DateofEncounter AND e.ApptID = e2.ApptID)
GROUP BY a.PatientID, a.ApptID
ORDER BY COUNT(e.EncounterID) DESC
```